# Is this sum differentiable?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $R$ be an infinite set of complex numbers $\rho$ with $0<\Re(\rho)<1$, $x$ be a nonzero real number and consider the summation $\sum_{\rho} x^{\rho}$. Is this sum differentiable with respect to $x$ ?

Comment: Forget differentiability; can you give an example for which the stated series _converges_...?

Answer (score 1):

If $\rho = a + bi$ (real and imaginary parts), $\log$ denotes the branch whose imaginary part lies in $(-\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$, and
\begin{align*}
x^{\rho}
  &= \exp\bigl((a + bi) \log x\bigr) \\
  &= \begin{cases}
    |x|^{a} \exp(ib\log x) & \text{if $x > 0$,} \\
    |x|^{a} e^{-b\pi} \exp\bigl(i(a\pi + b\log |x|)\bigr) & \text{if $x < 0$,} \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
then
$$
|x^{\rho}| = \begin{cases}
  |x|^{a} & \text{if $x > 0$,} \\
  |x|^{a} e^{-b\pi} & \text{if $x < 0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $0 < \min(|x|, 1) \leq |x|^{a} \leq \max(|x|, 1)$ for all real $x$ and all $0 < a = \Re(\rho) < 1$,

- $\sum\limits_{\rho \in R} x^{\rho}$ diverges for all $x > 0$ regardless of the infinite set $R$;
- $\sum\limits_{\rho \in R} x^{\rho}$ converges (absolutely) for all $x < 0$ if and only if $\sum\limits_{\rho \in R} e^{-b\pi}$ converges.

To answer the question, "No, the sum is not differentiable for non-zero real $x$", for the blunt reason that the sum makes no sense if $x > 0$ and generally makes no sense if $x < 0$.